# Pybind11 global variables do not change

Tags: c++, pybind11

I have a global variable in my header file example.h as follows:

```
int lst[10][10];
```

I want to assign values to its elements in Python. I want to use this element later in the C++ code. I used pybind11 as you can see below:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m){
m.attr("lst") = py::array({10, 10}, {10 * sizeof(int), sizeof(int)}, lst);
}
```

But when I try to assign values in Python, it does not change its value in C++ code, I cannot access it on C++ code. What should i do?